# php regex - clean file names

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking for elegant regular expression to **clean brackets** with content looks like file name.

```
[Nibh justo] elit Nulla [link.pdf]  auctor ipsum molestie (link.pdf) 
Condimentum euismod non [link.xls](link.xls) [link.doc](link.doc) tempus 
In [Curabitur] et
```

The result should be:

```
Nibh justo elit Nulla auctor ipsum molestie Condimentum euismod 
non tempus In Curabitur et
```

I trust there must be a short way do that.
(File means simply - dot included. No sentences check is necessary.)

thank for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$str = '[Nibh justo] elit Nulla [link.pdf]  auctor ipsum molestie (link.pdf) 
Condimentum euismod non [link.xls](link.xls) [link.doc](link.doc) tempus In 
[Curabitur] and other [./beta/link.pfd]';

$str = preg_replace('`(\(|\[)[\w/\.-]+\.[a-z]+(\)|\])`i', '', $str);
$str = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $str);

echo $str;
```

Result is :

```
Nibh justo elit Nulla auctor ipsum molestie Condimentum euismod 
non tempus In Curabitur and other
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

`(?:[\[\(]\w+\.\w+[\]\)])|(?:[\[\(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))|(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\]\)])`

`$result = preg_replace('/(?:[[(]\w+\.\w+[\])])|(?:[[(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))|(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\])])/m', '', $subject);`

**Explanation:**

```
    <!--
(?:[\[\(]\w+\.\w+[\]\)])|(?:[\[\(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))|(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\]\)])

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?:[\[\(]\w+\.\w+[\]\)])»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:[\[\(]\w+\.\w+[\]\)])»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\[\(]»
         A [ character «\[»
         A ( character «\(»
      Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
      Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\]\)]»
         A ] character «\]»
         A ) character «\)»
Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?:[\[\(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:[\[\(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\[\(]»
         A [ character «\[»
         A ( character «\(»
      Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=[0-9A-Za-z])»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[0-9A-Za-z]»
            A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
            A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
            A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\]\)])»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\]\)])»
      Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[0-9A-Za-z]»
            A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
            A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
            A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\]\)]»
         A ] character «\]»
         A ) character «\)»
-->
```

**when the above RegEx applied to :**

```
[Nibh justo] elit Nulla [link.pdf]  auctor ipsum molestie (link.pdf) 
Condimentum euismod non [link.xls](link.xls) [link.doc](link.doc) tempus 
In [Curabitur] et
```

**produces required result:**

```
Nibh justo elit Nulla   auctor ipsum molestie  
Condimentum euismod non   tempus 
In Curabitur et
```

Comment: yes. works perfect, but `Curabitur` still lost. Looks like it doesn't match single word in brackets.

Comment: Try this: ``(?:[\[\(]\w+\.\w+[\]\)])|(?:[\[\(](?=[0-9A-Za-z]))|(?:(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])[\]\)])``

Comment: Thank you for help. There is a lot of mismatches while the file links included dirs, but it helped while creating expr.

Comment: If you need to match ``filenames`` with or without ``dirs``, then the RegEx could be more simpler than that was being posted now!